# Как написать хороший заголовок?

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка, faq

Хороший, правильно подобранный заголовок помогает привлечь к вашему вопросу заслуженное внимание. Что можно считать хорошим заголовком?

---

<sub>Перевод вопроса «[How do I write a good title?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10647/274323)».</sub>

Answer (score 7):

**1. Сделайте свою тему заметной.**

Цель заголовка – привлечь внимание людей, заинтересованных в вашей теме – или тех, кто сможет дать ответ на ваш вопрос. Люди склонны быстро просматривать страницы сайта – сделайте так, чтобы ваш заголовок бросался в глаза. Некоторые читают страницы с помощью [RSS
лент](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSS) <sup><sub>([например, Stack Overflow на русском](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/feeds))</sub></sup>, поэтому не видят меток.

**2. Чем короче – тем лучше.**

Нет необходимости перегружать заголовок подробностями – сделайте это в теле вопроса.

Аналогично, не старайтесь сформулировать заголовок как грамматически завершенное предложение – достаточно основной мысли.

**3. Начните с самых важных слов.**

[В этих](http://www.useit.com/eyetracking) [статьях](http://www.useit.com/alertbox/reading_pattern.html) приведены выводы о том, как люди читают страницы сайтов – на основании исследований, включавших слежение за движениями человеческого глаза во время чтения. На страницах сайтов на подобие Stack Overflow люди прочитывают большую часть первого и второго блока (горизонтальные линии латинской буквы "F"), а затем «сканируют» остальной список сверху вниз, читая в среднем первые 16 символов каждой строки.

[image: Карта внимания]

**4. Не начинайте заголовок с фразы "Как мне..."**

Такой стиль нарушает критерии 1-3, а заголовок привлекает меньше внимания, чем того заслуживает.

Stack Overflow – сайт вопросов-ответов, и люди по умолчанию будут воспринимать ваш заголовок как вопрос.

**5. Не старайтесь сформулировать заголовок так, чтобы в него попало как можно больше ключевых слов.**

Ключевые слова «ортогональны» заголовку, то есть от него не зависят. Если вопрос касается определенной темы, скорее всего, удачным заголовком к нему будет упоминание названия этой темы. Взгляните на первую страницу – это довольно распространено.

**6. Пример удачного заголовка: "Что такое ..."**

Поскольку продолжение этого вопроса, как правило, можно сформулировать в двух словах, подобные заголовки все еще очень емко и сжато описывают суть вопроса.

**Удачные примеры**

Несколько примеров удачных заголовков: суть вопроса в них изложена точно и лаконично, в то же время, привлекая внимание читателя, «сканирующего» список вопросов.

- Включение/Выключение USB-питания под Linux
- Как выполнить UPSERT в Oracle (обновить и вставить в таблицу)?
- Python: какая у меня OS?
- Сделать активным существующее окно X11 из командной строки
- Значения 64-bit XML-RPC?
- Изменение положения существующего окна X11 из командной строки
- Сложение 3х столбцов в SQL, если один из них имеет нулевое значение
- Oracle: поиск в диапазоне величин
- Зашифрованные резервные копии PostgreSQL
- Читабельный шрифт для представления кода
- Объектно-ориентированные vs. реляционные базы данных
- Oracle: форматирование числа как xxx-xx-xxxx
- PostgreSQL Long VACUUM
- Самый быстродействующий метод в C
- Система планирования маршрутов по карте по типу Google Maps
- Конструирование изображения с помощью HTML-разметки
- Быстрая вставка PostgreSQL BLOBs

**Несколько неудачных примеров**

Следующие заголовки, также взятые из реальной жизни, подробно описывают вопрос, но затрудняют восприятие его сути при «сканировании» списком.

- Как мне отформатировать xxxxxxxxx как xxx-xx-xxxx в Oracle?
- Как мне программными средствами включить и отключить питание определенного USB-порта на Linux?
- Как поднять существующее окно с помощью командной строки в X11?
- Как быстро вставить BLOB в PostgreSQL?
- Как переместить существующее окно с помощью командной строки в X11?
- Как сохранить несколько элементов XML-файла, чтобы их было легко обрабатывать?
- Какой шрифт лучше использовать в презентации для кода?
- Как конструировать изображения с помощью HTML-разметки?
- Какая книга по разработке ПО самая лучшая?
- Как генерировать уникальные случайные числа в PHP?
- Как мне понять, на какой ОС я работаю на Python?

**И, наконец, будьте гибки**

Право на жизнь имеют разные заголовки, и единого жесткого правила на этот счет не существует.

Comment: В удачных примерах: "Python, Oracle, PostgreSQL" - должны ли быть ключевые слова в заголовке? Не лучше ли удалить их, перенеся в теги.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Они должны быть в метках. При этом название технологии допускается в заголовке. Например, Python: как экранировать символы в строке.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Как ни странно, [справочный центр](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) говорит, что лучше не использовать метки в заголовке вопросов. Как мне кажется, основная технология в заголовке вопроса полезна лишь в случае использования RSS–лент.