# Ссылка на единственного автора общего вопроса/ответа

Tags: дефект, общие-сообщения

Когда [вопрос](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3342/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BA) или ответ делается "общим", ссылка на имени автора ведет на страницу ревизий, а не на профиль автора.

> [image: линк]

Такое поведение мне кажется нелогичным.

Для [двух](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/541022/176217) и более авторов ссылки ведут на профиль:

> [image: линк2]

Текущее поведение оформлено как Bug Report на MSE: [Clicking User's Name Leads Me to Editing History of Question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/253972/339911)

Answer (score 2):

Главная задача общих сообщений – дать возможность сообществу коллективно поддерживать общие знания. [Идеологически, у таких сообщений нет как такового автора](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/158607/274323) в контексте владения, что, в свою очередь, отражается в правах на управление сообщением. В текущей реализации отображается участник, внесший наибольших вклад в содержимое сообщения. Когда у общего сообщения лишь одна правка, дополнительная информация о редакциях – излишня.

С другой стороны, сообщество хотело, чтобы у каждого вопроса был автор в том или ином виде. Как результат, [если есть такая возможность, то автор указывается](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/180729/274323).

[По нашему мнению](https://blog.codinghorror.com/mixing-oil-and-water-authorship-in-a-wiki-world/), авторитет автора, внесшего наибольший вклад, сильно влияет на восприятие информации в сообщении.

В случаях, если автор, внесший наибольший вклад в содержимое сообщения, удалил свою учётную запись, [ссылка становится единой](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238589/) и ведет на страницу редакций.

Comment: По второму абзацу получается, что возможности по-прежнему нет. Комменты по ссылке подтверждают это. То есть, не 'так задумано', а скорее 'еще не реализовано'. Или я не прав?

Comment: На сколько я понимаю (но могу ошибаться), возможность есть и она используется – имя «автора» всегда отображается, но оно не всегда будет ссылкой.

Comment: "linking to the mentioned user's profile" ... ссылаться на профиль пользователя.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/253972

Comment: Да, «сам черт ногу сломит». Я на всякий случай отпишусь разработчикам в чате. Если это дефект, добавлю соответствующую метку.