# Как правильно изменять заголовок вопроса

Tags: обсуждение, заголовок

Вот пример [вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1095183/195342), в котором есть проблема со сравнением строк, но заголовок отражает непонимание сути проблемы автором вопроса.

С метками как-то понятнее - убрал те, что к делу не относятся, добавил те, которые имеют отношение к решению, и все в порядке.

А вот как быть с заголовком? Не менять? Он будет бесполезен и, более того, дезориентировать при поиске. Поменять? А как? В данном конкретном случае - как "*Сравнение C-строк*"? Но автора волнует совсем не это, и в вопросе вообще нет ничего об этом (он и понятия не имеет, в чем на самом деле его проблема).

Как лучше поступать в такой ситуации?...

Comment: И заголовок, и метки не обязательно должны отражать сущность вопроса после его решения. Основной критерий -- насколько вероятно, что кто-то с "багажом" как у автора вопроса в поисковике попытается найти решение для схожей  проблемы и топик с решением окажется в топе результатов поиска. Другими словами, насколько вероятно, что аргументы переданные через консоль кто-то начнёт сравнивать так же "по простому", и какие ключевые слова ему придут на ум.  _сравнение c-строк_ скорее всего нет, a _арргумент  консоль_ очень даже вероятно.

Comment: @0xdb а чего ответом не оформите? )

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica Потому, что пока очень субъективное мнение. Это я так пытаюсь "войти в положение"  того, у кого потенциально подобная проблема возникнет.  Получается ли у меня хорошо, я не знаю.

Comment: @0xdb Как вы считаете, какая вероятность больше - что задающий вопрос сначала выполнит поиск по *правильному* критерию, или что он выполнит поиск по *неправильному* критерию, но совпадающему с неправильным же критерием другого человека? Конкретнее - какова вероятность поиска решения проблемы сравнения строк как "передача аргументов через консоль Windows"? Мне, откровенно, слабо верится, что два непонимания будут столь одинаковы...

Comment: @Harry Зависит от контекста, в котором проблема возникнет. Например: 1) Если некто  объявит си строку в c++ контексте и попытается ее в if вставить, то он вероятнее будет искать "сравнить си строку" и быстро найдёт решение. 2) Теперь некто пытается первый раз воспользоваться аргументами для своей привет-мир. Что первое ему придёт на ум - что-то у меня с аргументами не так. Насколько он быстро сообразит, что он сравнивает си строки, ведь они обьявлены для него неявно.

Comment: @Harry, *`"какая вероятность больше..."`*  в вопросах, которые вы рассматриваете обе близки к 0. Если бы люди, задающие такие вопросы, посидели часок-другой в гугле, мы бы тут на 90% стали не нужны.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Тут первый вопрос, который стоит задать - **когда** стоит изменять заголовок вопроса. Наиболее общий ответ: "Когда вы можете привести его в соответствие с рекомендациями из темы [Как написать хороший заголовок?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3342/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BA?rq=1), не меняя его смысла (при наличии такового), и когда вопрос с ответами имеет какой-то потенциал для "Базы Знаний". Как именно редактировать зависит от того, какая проблема у заголовка. Например, бессмысленный заголовок ("Не работает программа", "Помогите решить задачу") можно заменить на осмысленный, а слишком общий заголовок ("Работа со строками в С++") можно заменить на более конкретный.

В данном случае ответ видимо **Никак**. Вопрос - типичный из серии "отладьте за меня". Автор не сузил свой код до того, чтобы он мог продемонстрировать конкретную проблему сравнения строк, там в кучу и аргументы командной строки, и работа с файлами, и какая-то самодельная криптография. Кроме того, сравнение строк по указателю - распространенная ошибка новичков, и у нас уже есть отвеченные вопросы на эту тему: [Строка не равна введенной пользователем строке c++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/228084/). Это не значит, что вопрос надо минусовать или что на него нельзя дать полезный ответ. Просто не любой вопрос заслуживает усилий на придумывание красивого заголовка.

Comment: Если вопрос **не** имеет какой-то потенциал для "Базы Знаний" - его лучше вообще удалять, нет?

Comment: @Harry Это не совсем так. Не любой плохой вопрос достаточно плох для удаления. Ответы с подробным разбором проблем конкретного кода тоже могут быть полезны, хоть их и не найдут из поисковиков по запросам, но кто-то может случайно их прочитать и избежать таких же ошибок в дальнейшем. Удаляем мы в основном очевидный мусор.

Comment: Ну, будем считать, что уговорили... Все равно "база знаний" давно перестала ею быть...